# Any way to optimize this character counter i wrote in ruby for String class

Tags: ruby, string, oop, range

```
# Character Counter
class String
  def count_lcases
    count(('a'..'z').to_a.join(''))
  end

  def count_upcases
    count(('A'..'Z').to_a.join(''))
  end

  def count_num
    count((0..9).to_a.join(''))
  end

  def count_spl_chars
    length - count_lcases - count_upcases - count_num
  end
end

input = ARGV[0]

if ARGV.empty?
  puts 'Please provide an input'
  exit
end

puts 'Lowercase characters = %d' % [input.count_lcases]
puts 'Uppercase characters = %d' % [input.count_upcases]
puts 'Numeric characters = %d' % [input.count_num]
puts 'Special characters = %d' % [input.count_spl_chars]
```

I used ranges to count characters but count function is called 3 times.

I can always use loops and count it one by one.I was wondering is there any way to optimize this?...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com - perhaps try asking there.

Comment: You could traverse the string once and store the occurrences in a hash. To keep things easy and clean, I'd move everything in a separate class `CharacterCounter`, pass the string to `initialize` and work on a copy. (so you don't have to deal with mutability)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Ruby 2.7 you could use [tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally); the string's chars are just iterated one time.

```
def classify_char(c)
  case c
    when /[a-z]/ then :lcase 
    when /[A-Z]/ then :ucase
    when /\d/    then :digit
    else :other
  end
end

p "asg3456  ERTYaeth".chars.map{|c| classify_char(c) }.tally
# => {:lcase=>7, :digit=>4, :other=>2, :ucase=>4}
```

Comment: I understand there are discussions of also adding `Enumerable#tally_by`, which would allow one to write `str.each_char.tally_by { |c| classify_char(c) }`.

Comment: @Cary Yes that would be nice. I actually checked if `tally` would take a block (it does, but ignores it).

Comment: I did as well, as was surprised that it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

If Ruby 2.3...2.7, this will work:

```
CHAR_CLASSES = {
  lcase: ?a..?z,
  ucase: ?A..?Z,
  digit: ?0..?9,
}

p "asg3456  ERTYaeth".each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c, o|
  o[CHAR_CLASSES.find { |label, group| group === c }&.first || :other] += 1
}
```

For < 2.3,

```
p "asg3456  ERTYaeth".each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c, o|
  p = CHAR_CLASSES.find { |label, group| group === c }
  o[p ? p.first : :other] += 1
}
```